# Can Dapper handle null values in a return?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, dapper

I'm calling the Dapper extended function `Query` for the `IDbConnection` class. The problem is, some of the values its returning are `NULL` in the database. It keeps complaining about them, so I've been converting the members of my return class to nullable types. But I'm thinking I may end up doing this for almost every member, because the data is often incomplete. This is being changed from older code that uses the `DataRow` class and is able to assign empty values from it to `string` members of my return class without any problems using just `ToString`.

```
public class ProductInfo
{
    public Char Department { get; set; }
}
```

This works:

```
ProductInfo myProduct = new ProductInfo{};
myProduct.Department = dataRow["department"].ToString();
```

`dataRow["department"]` shows as `{}` and `myProduct.Department` shows as `""`.

This gives an exception:

```
List<ProductInfo> myProduct = new List<ProductInfo>();
myProduct = dbConnection.Query<ProductInfo>(command, parameters).ToList();
```

Wtih the error: `Error parsing column 1 (department=<null>) Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null`

Am I missing a step in the process Dapper uses to assign values? Or is extensive use of nullable types standard practice with it?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a limitation with Dapper; it's how your model is setup.

A `char` type isn't nullable.

Change your model to `char?` to make it nullable.

Comment: I can see how my question could be ambiguous. I am aware of that solution and have been using it. My example was simply to show what happens without a nullable type. I'm wondering if there's an alternate way to set Dapper to handle nulls by e.g. converting them to empty strings or 0s or whatever before trying to assign them to the class members.

Comment: The conversion would have to be done in your SQL, e.g. SQL's `isnull` or `coalesce` operators.